eslint - going in circles
I'm getting an error in eslint:
C:\Users\prima\yeld\components\stock\valuation.tsx
  3:58  error  Can't resolve '@/components/ui/card' in 'C:\Users\prima\yeld\components\stock' 

For some reason eslint is looking for card in components\stock\ui\card when I run
npx eslint --debug --verbose components/stock/valuation.tsx

instead of components/ui
I've installed:
I've installed the vscode: eslint, prettier and prettier eslint extensions.  After many hours of trying to figure out what is going on I have:
I have several ESLint-related packages installed:
Core ESLint packages:
eslint (version ^8)
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser for TypeScript support
ESLint configurations:
eslint-config-next for Next.js
eslint-config-prettier for Prettier integration
ESLint plugins and resolvers:
eslint-plugin-import for ES6+ import/export syntax
eslint-plugin-n (Node.js-specific rules)
eslint-plugin-prettier for Prettier integration
eslint-import-resolver-alias and eslint-import-resolver-typescript for import resolution
Suggestions?
Thanks!
My tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

my eslint.config.js file is:
import eslint from '@eslint/js'
import n from 'eslint-plugin-n'
import tseslint from '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
import tsParser from '@typescript-eslint/parser'
import prettier from 'eslint-plugin-prettier'
import importPlugin from 'eslint-plugin-import'

export default [
  {
    ignores: ['lib/**', 'node_modules/**', 'pnpm-lock.yaml'],
  },
  {
    linterOptions: {
      reportUnusedDisableDirectives: 'error',
    },
  },
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  n.configs['flat/recommended'],
  {
    files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
    languageOptions: {
      parser: tsParser,
      parserOptions: {
        project: './tsconfig.json',
        tsconfigRootDir: import.meta.dirname,
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: 'module',
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      '@typescript-eslint': tseslint,
      prettier: prettier,
      import: importPlugin,
    },
    settings: {
      'n/resolve': {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        paths: ['.'],
      },
      'import/parsers': {
        '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
      'import/resolver': {
        typescript: {
          alwaysTryTypes: true,
          project: './tsconfig.json',
        },
        alias: {
          map: [['@', './']],
          extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
        },
      },
    },
    rules: {
      'no-constant-condition': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error', { caughtErrors: 'all' }],
      'prettier/prettier': 'error',
      'no-unused-vars': 'warn', // From .eslintrc.json, adjusting for consistency
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['*.jsonc'],
    rules: {
      'jsonc/comma-dangle': 'off',
      'jsonc/no-comments': 'off',
      'jsonc/sort-keys': 'error',
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.md/*.ts'],
    extends: ['plugin:@typescript-eslint/disable-type-checked'],
    rules: {
      'n/no-missing-import': ['error', { allowModules: ['yielding'] }],
    },
  },
]


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].
